# SQL INNER JOIN DISTINCT with max function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the tables tbMeasurement  and tbPatientMeasurement .

**tbMeasurement**

```
MeasurementIDP
MeasurementName
```

**tbPatientMeasurement**

```
PatientMeasurementIDP
MeasurementIDF
MeasurementValue
Taken (Datetime)
```

When doing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.tbMeasurement.MeasurementName
      , dbo.tbPatientMeasurement.MeasurementValue
      , dbo.tbPatientMeasurement.Taken
  FROM dbo.tbMeasurement
 INNER JOIN dbo.tbPatientMeasurement
   ON  dbo.tbMeasurement.MeasurementIDP = dbo.tbPatientMeasurement.MeasurementIDF
```

This returns a double entry of one of the MeasurementName. 
and i also want `MeasurementName,MeasurementValue by max Taken(datetime).`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please correctly tag your question, wich RDBMS are you using, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, other? This way you will gain more visibility and more opportunities to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  
      m.MeasurementName
    , p.MeasurementValue
    , a.Taken 
FROM dbo.tbMeasurement m
INNER JOIN dbo.tbPatientMeasurement p ON m.MeasurementIDP = p.MeasurementIDF
INNER JOIN
(
select MeasurementIDF,MAX(Taken) as taken 
from tbPatientMeasurement
group by MeasurementIDF
) a on a.MeasurementIDF=p.MeasurementIDF and a.taken=p.Taken
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this one -

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      m.MeasurementName
    , p2.MeasurementValue
    , p2.Taken
FROM dbo.tbMeasurement m
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          p.MeasurementValue
        , Taken = MAX(p.Taken) 
    FROM dbo.tbPatientMeasurement p 
    GROUP BY m.MeasurementName, p.MeasurementValue
) p2 ON m.MeasurementIDP = p2.MeasurementIDF
```

Comment: You were asked to specify SQL server type - solution depends on it.

Comment: i am using SQL server 2005 and new with sql server so i don't know about SQL Server type.